# Toggle between two java version for JetBrain development

Tags: java, jetbrains-ide

I'm using one JDK1.7 for one project and JDK 1.8 for another. Is there a way to toggle between both while using the respective projects? right now, I have to manually change the versions in the 'User & System variables' every time I open the project.

Thanks!

Comment: You're changing system JDK. IDEA allows to set project JDK.

Comment: @chipmunk Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the "Project SDK" in the Project Structure menu :

[image]

If you are talking about different modules that require different Java versions, you can also change the "Module SDK" version in the Modules menu (Dependencies tab).

[image]

Comment: Point for you, but I must add that this beautiful product of course has fitting documentation; this was a quick search on the site: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html